# Sort a collection on a calculated value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo database with two collections:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', {
    title : String,
    text : String,
    topics : Array,
    category : String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', {
    email        : String,
    password     : String,
    topics       : [{
                        _id: false,
                        topic: String,
                        interest: {type: Number, default: 0}
                    }]
});
```

The article topics field contains article topics, while the user topic field contains topics with related interests of the user.

I would like to make a query that returns the articles sorted by a field that is the linear combination of the topics array of the article and the topics array of an user given an ID (current user).

For example if Article topics is: 
["food", "pizza", "pasta"]
and User topics is: 
[{topic: "car", interest: 2} , {topic: "pizza", interest: 5} , {topic: "pasta", interest: 1} ]

projectField = 5 + 1 = 6, as pizza and pasta coincide.

Then I would like to order on that field.

How can I do it?

I would like to get something like that:

```
Users.findById(req.user._id).exec(function (err, user) {
            Article.aggregate([
                {
                    // projectField = sum user.topics.interest for any user.topics.topic in topics
                },
                { $sort : { projectField : -1} }
            ], function (err, articles) {
                console.log(articles);
            });
        });
```

Comment: Fetch an article, get the topics from there, aggregate users [filtering](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) their topics. Show the code if you face any particular problems.

Comment: I updated the question by adding my naive approach.

Comment: @AlexBlex Actually it would make a lot more sense to simply `$map` the array from the `User` instead of "filtering" anything. At least that's my take on it and the approach I used here.

Comment: @NeilLunn, yeah, nice one. Should work with minimal tweaks.

Comment: @AlexBlex What tweaks? Fully working answer already presented. Nothing to change here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to feed this through `.aggregate()` and then sort on the calculated value.

So in essence. You are already going to have the selected `User` object in memory, but we'll consider it a selection and continue on from the promise:

```
User.findById(userId).then(user =>

  Arictle.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
      "score": {
        "$sum": {
          "$map": {
            "input": user.topics,
            "as": "u",
            "in": {
              "$cond": {
                "if": { "$setIsSubset": [ ["$$u.topic"], "$topics" ] },
                "then": "$$u.interest",
                "else": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "score": -1 } }
  ])

).then( results => {
  // work with results here
});
```

So essentially we provide the "array" from the `User` and give it as the argument to [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), which frankly takes "any array" and does not need to be part of the document itself.

As you iterate each item, the comparison is made to the `"topics"` in the current `Article` to see if there is a match on the current `"topic"` in the `User` supplied array. That comparison is done by [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/), remembering to wrap the singular value in an array for comparison of course.

When it does match we supply the `interest` value, or otherwise `0`. The "mapped" array is then fed to [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/), and you get a "score" which can then be sorted in a latter stage.

Technically speaking you could instead provide the input to [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) from [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) instead of using [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) inside to determine the output, but the syntax to do so is "a little more terse" so it's avoided in favor of using [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to "swap" the values.

When it's all done, you simply [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) on the calculated field and that's your results.

If needed, add [`$skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) stages, or better yet a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) "after" all the calculation and "sorting" is done to implement "paging" of results. But the basic process is here.

> **Note:** The [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) pipeline stage would be the optimal thing to use since you only need supply the "new" field, and it is appended to the document. If your MongoDB version does not support this pipeline stage, then simply replace with [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), noting that instead you **must** explicitly specify **every** field you want to return in the document, with the addition of the new calculated field. But there is absolutely no other difference in the implemented logic.

---

### Full Listing

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/interests',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const articleSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  text: String,
  topics: [String],
  category: String
});

const Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  topics: [{
    _id: false,
    topic: String,
    interest: { type: Number, default: 0 }
  }]
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2))
}


// Main program
(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    await Promise.all(
      Object.keys(conn.models).map( m => conn.models[m].remove({}))
    );


    // Create Some Data
    let user = await User.create({
      email: 'bill@example.com',
      topics: [
        { topic: 'pizza', interest: 5 },
        { topic: 'pasta', interest: 1 }
      ]
    });
    log(user);

    let article = await Article.create({
      title: 'test',
      topics: ["food","pizza","pasta"]
    });
    log(article);

    // Fetch and aggregate

    user = await User.findById(user._id);

    let results = await Article.aggregate([
      { "$addFields": {
        "score": {
          "$sum": {
            "$map": {
              "input": user.topics,
              "as": "u",
              "in": {
                "$cond": {
                  "if": { "$setIsSubset": [ ["$$u.topic"], "$topics" ] },
                  "then": "$$u.interest",
                  "else": 0
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "score": -1 } }
    ]);
    log(results);

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }

})();
```

Produces the results:

```
Mongoose: articles.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: users.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: users.insert({ email: 'bill@example.com', _id: ObjectId("5970969d3248a329766d5e72"), topics: [ { topic: 'pizza', interest: 5 }, { topic: 'pasta', interest: 1 } ], __v: 0 })
{
  "__v": 0,
  "email": "bill@example.com",
  "_id": "5970969d3248a329766d5e72",
  "topics": [
    {
      "topic": "pizza",
      "interest": 5
    },
    {
      "topic": "pasta",
      "interest": 1
    }
  ]
}
Mongoose: articles.insert({ title: 'test', _id: ObjectId("5970969d3248a329766d5e73"), topics: [ 'food', 'pizza', 'pasta' ], __v: 0 })
{
  "__v": 0,
  "title": "test",
  "_id": "5970969d3248a329766d5e73",
  "topics": [
    "food",
    "pizza",
    "pasta"
  ]
}
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5970969d3248a329766d5e72") }, { fields: {} })
Mongoose: articles.aggregate([ { '$addFields': { score: { '$sum': { '$map': { input: [ { interest: 5, topic: 'pizza' }, { interest: 1, topic: 'pasta' } ], as: 'u', in: { '$cond': { if: { '$setIsSubset': [ [ '$$u.topic' ], '$topics' ] }, then: '$$u.interest', else: 0 } } } } } } }, { '$sort': { score: -1 } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5970969d3248a329766d5e73",
    "title": "test",
    "topics": [
      "food",
      "pizza",
      "pasta"
    ],
    "__v": 0,
    "score": 6
  }
]
```

Comment: Perfect excellence. I grasped the concept.
I still can not understand why I get this error: "MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$ setIsSubSet'" even though my version (db.version ()) is 3.4.2 and in the documentation it says it is supported by versions >= 2.6

Comment: @GabrielePicco It was a "typo" by me that was fixed since you copied the code. It's `$setIsSubset` just like it says in the rest of the text in the answer.

Comment: @GabrielePicco Added a full listing and output for you. I do actually know these things work when I submit them as answers. And more often than not I give an example as run by myself reproducing the same conditions you ask in the question. Just like here.

Comment: My fault I did not control ! Thanks, your answer is perfect !